# NoReverseMatch at /cart/add-to-cart/1/ Reverse for 'single_product' with arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<slug>.*)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

am having a function `add_to_cart` wanted to reverse redirect to product detail page rendered by `single_product` function which has slug for product id , cant get a way to solve it .getting this error

> Reverse for 'single_product' with arguments '('s', 'l', 'u', 'g')'
>   not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P.*)/$']

```
def add_to_cart(request,**kwargs):
     product = Product.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get('item_id', "")).first()
    # check if the user already owns this product
    ----------------

    -------------
    messages.info(request, "item added to cart")
    return redirect(reverse('products:single_product',args=('slug')))
```

url for product detail view

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$',single, name="single_product"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `args` should contain a *single* parameter, you need to construct a *singleton tuple*. You can do so by adding a comma at the end:

```
def add_to_cart(request,**kwargs):
    # ...
    return redirect(reverse('products:single_product',args=(product.slug,)))
    #                                                   singleton tuple ^
```

Note that you can however write parameters directly in the [**`redirect(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), in that case `redirect(..)` will call [**`reverse(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) itself, as is specified in the documentation:

> The arguments could be:
>
> - A model: the model's `get_absolute_url()` function will be called.
> - A **view name, possibly with arguments**: `reverse()` will be used to reverse-resolve the name.
> - An absolute or relative URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.

So a more compact form to redirect to this view, is just:

```
def add_to_cart(request,**kwargs):
    # ...
    return redirect('products:single_product', product.slug)
    #                     positional parameter ^
```

or more verbose:

```
def add_to_cart(request,**kwargs):
    # ...
    return redirect('products:single_product', slug=product.slug)
    #                          named parameter ^
```

`redirect(..)` makes use of `*args` and `**kwargs`, so here you do not need to pass a tuple or dictionary.

If your `Product` class has a `get_absolute_url` method, then you can simply pass your `product` object:

```
def add_to_cart(request,**kwargs):
    product = Product.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get('item_id', "")).first()
    # ...
    return redirect(product)
```

Note however that if `product` is `None`, the above will of course fail, since `None` has no `get_absolute_url` method.

Comment: is reverse omitted ?

Comment: @Cipher: as the documentation says on `redirect(..)` you can pass "*A view name, possibly with arguments: reverse() will be used to reverse-resolve the name.*".

Comment: Both options don work error no product marching a query and no module named slug so the url goes to /products/slug/ instead of /products/productname/

Comment: @Cipher: but that is not due to the reverse anymore. That is (likely) because the page to which you redirect contains some errors (or the URL you provided simply is non-sensical). You probably do not want to pass `slug` hardcoded?

Comment: I suggest that you take a look to where the browser has redirected you, and where the new error occurs (run this with `debug=True`).

Comment: http://localhost:8000/products/slug/ instead of http://localhost:8000/products/productname/

Comment: @Cipher: well then likely the parameter is `product.slug` (or something similar) instead of a hardcoded `'slug'` string... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196592/discussion-between-cipher-and-willem-van-onsem).